# Compare dd-mm-yyyy datetime

Tags: c#, linq, date, linq-to-entities

### Problem

I want to compare "dd-mm-yyyy" DateTime's without factoring in the time.

### Attempt

I have tried comparing the standard DateTime values with my database DateTime's like this:

**C#/LINQ:**

```
 var startDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-10);
 var endDate = DateTime.Today;     
     dateList= (from x in db.MY_DB
         where (x.DATE >= startDate && x.DATE < endDate)   
         select x).ToList();
```

However, my list never gets populated, even though many entries meet this criteria, which I verified with the following query in SQL:

**SQL Query:**

```
Select * from db.my_db where date between '13-JUN-2016' and '23-JUN-2016';
```

Comment: Dates have no format, they are binary values. The date part of a DateTime is returned by the `Date` property. The time part by the `Time` property. You also *don't* need to use `DateTime.Now` if you want today's date, use `DateTime.Today`

Comment: What is the datatype of the column DATE from your db table?

Comment: And what ORM are  you using? LINQ can be LINQ to Objects or to a database using, eg EF or NHibernate.

Comment: Maybe do `var end = DateTime.Now.Date;` then  in your query `x.DATE < end`?

Comment: BTW if the column is `varchar` and has *that* format, you are in serious trouble as that format isn't sortable. You'd have to cast the column value to a date first, which would prevent you from using any indexes

Comment: @Steve, the datatype for DATE is DateTime.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, LINQ to Entities.

Comment: @ThanksInAdvance then you shouldn't have a problem to perform a straight comparison between dates.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos after looking into it more, I see what you're saying about the being able to perform a straight comparison. None of the entries are populating the list though. I have tried the same query directly in SQL and it works, so any ideas on why the same linq query isn't working?

Comment: That's impossible to answer without a sample of the data and the *exact* SQL query you used. There is no DateTime.Now` in SQL, so what did you write? How did you pass the date literal? Did you use the unseparated format for the date, ie `YYYYMMDD`, or did you use US-style dates? Are you *sure* the values you are seeing are in MM/YY? Try searching since Dec 31 using the unseparated format, ie '20151231'. Do the results differ between Linq-to-Entities and raw SQL?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I got rid of the '.Now' part. Sorry for the confusion but just realized that I'm using Italian style dates (dd-mm-yyyy), and here's the SQL query I used to check if the values exist: "Select * from db.tb where date between '13-JUN-2016' and '23-JUN-2016';". Would the style matter though? I thought that DateTime format doesn't matter when comparing?

Comment: There is no such thing as a DateTime format. Post *both* the C# code and the SQL statement. If there are any differences it means that the queries are different or that the dates in SQL are not what you expected. Also *don't* use localized strings, use the unseparated format to make sure there are no conversions involved

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I updated my question with the C# and SQL used.

Comment: @ThanksInAdvance here is some good reading - while you are waiting around based on your last question that got quickly downvoted.. - [Why doesn't C Support Multiple Inheritance](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/03/07/why-doesnt-c-support-multiple-inheritance/)

Comment: Thanks a lot @MethodMan! Now that I've reviewed everything, it makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` or `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` based on your Entity Framework version which:

> When used as part of a LINQ to Entities query, this method invokes the
>   canonical TruncateTime EDM function to return the given date with the
>   time portion cleared.

```
var start = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-10);
dateList = (from x in db.MY_DB
    where ((DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DATE) < DateTime.Now.Date) &&
    ((DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DATE) >= start)
    select x).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried this but I get the error: "The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities"

Comment: @ThanksInAdvance based on your EF version:  use `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220142(v=vs.113).aspx or `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime`  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596.aspx

Comment: @user3185569 there's no need for that. You *don't* need to trim the column's value. `x.Date < DateTime.Now` is enough for any past values. So is `x.Date >=start` for any values on or after `start`, because `start` has a 0 time part

Answer (score 0):

Dates have no format, they are binary values. If the type of the database column is one of the date types, eg `date`, `datetime`, `datetime2` etc, you could search for any record in the past 10 days like this:

```
var startDate=DateTime.Today.AddDays(-10);
var dateQuery=from row in db.MyTable
              where row.Date >=startDate;
```

To search for a date up to now:

```
var startDate=DateTime.Today.AddDays(-10);
var endDate=DateTime.Now;
var dateQuery=from row in db.MyTable
              where row.Date >=startDate && row.Date<endDate;
```

If there is any chance that there are entries today that occur later that `Now`, you can change the end parameter to tomorrow midnight. The rest of the query remains the same:

```
var startDate=DateTime.Today.AddDays(-10);
var endDate=DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);

var dateQuery=from row in db.MyTable
              where row.Date >=startDate && row.Date<endDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Microsoft Northwind example db, I wrote the equivalent LINQ:

```
var endDate = new DateTime(1996, 8, 1);
var startDate = endDate.AddDays(-10);
var dateList= (from x in Orders
    where (x.OrderDate >= startDate && x.OrderDate < endDate)   
    select x).ToList();
dateList.Dump();
```

and to worked exactly right.

Now, I'm going to assume that you are using Oracle, which I'm pretty sure uses that date display format, which call into question the accuracy of the Linq to PL-SQL transaction.  As I recall, that's handled by a third-party provider